# How can I add some line separators to my announcement list "AllItem" View?

Tags: master-page, custom-list, page-layout, css

I have added an announcement list to my SharePoint 2013 project, but on the Allitem view I need to add a line or boarder to each announcement list item, to separate the items more clearly. currently the items will be displayed as one block and the user need to hover over the item to view its boarders.
So can anyone advice if it is possible to add such separators?

[image]

Thanks

**Edit**
After adding the following style :-

```
<style>
.ms-listviewtable tr
{
 outline: thin solid red;
}
</style>
```

the result will be as follow:-

[image]

where the boarder for the list header will be inconsistent with the other boarders, and also the "item options" & "list option" menus were removed .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use views to see the items in a list or library that are most important to you or that fit a particular purpose. For example, you can create views of the files in a library that apply to a specific department or the items in a list that were created by a specific person. Views are available for the list or library you create them in.

Each list or library has at least one view. In the browser, you can modify these views and create new views. For example, a task list includes several views, such as All Tasks and My Tasks. You could modify these views by changing how the items in the list are sorted. Or you could create a new view that shows only that tasks that are incomplete.

For your requirement, you can goto --> Modify view --> under style --> you can select the styles you want.

Have a look at the below link for more details about styles in List/Library view

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-HA102774516.aspx#_Toc337729214)

In the above link, scroll down and find the Section named "Style" under "Settings for views" and it might help you to do your requirement.

Comment: but none of the defualt view templates provides boarders to the current view.

Comment: @johnG, You can try with the boxed or Document details styles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the boxed is very bad UI , and there is no "Document details" style for the announcement list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this list to a page and add the content editor webpart with the following styles. The following will work if this is the only list view webpart in the page. or else this styles will be applied to all the list views in that page.

```
<style>
.ms-listviewtable tr
{
 outline: thin solid red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried adding the style as a code snippet, but the results were not consistent , also the “item options” & “List Options” lists were removed after applying the style. Can you check my edit please for more detials?